# Dagger Components with multiple services

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I need to implement services as done in Spring using Dagger but I am unable to do so. Consider the following example.

This is one of the service

```
public class Service1 {
    private final Repository1 repo1;

    @Inject
    public Service1(Repository1 repo1) {
        this.repo1 = repo1;
    }
    // implementation
}
```

The module for this service is as under:

```
@Module
public class Service1Module {

   @Provides
   Repository1 provideRepository1(){
       return Repository1Impl.getInstance();
   }

   @Provides
   Service1 provideService1(){
      return new Service1Impl(this.provideRepository1());
   }
}
```

A component would be easily created for this module and be used. Simple and easy.

Now consider another class

```
public class Service2 {
    private final Repository2 repo2;
    private final Service1 service1;

    @Inject
    public Service2(Repository2 repo2, Service1 service1) {
       this.repo2 = repo2;
       this.service1 = service1;
    }
    // implementation
}
```

And we change the original class to

```
public class Service1 {
    private final Repository1 repo1;
    private final Service2 service2;

    @Inject
    public Service1(Repository1 repo1, Service2 service2) {
       this.repo1 = repo1;
       this.service2 = service2;
    }
    // implementation
}
```

The problem now is that I am unable to create a proper module with this approach.

Consider module class again

```
@Module
public class Service1Module {

     @Provides
     Repository1 provideRepository1(){
         return Repository1Impl.getInstance();
     }

     @Provides
     Repository2 provideRepository2(){
         return Repository2Impl.getInstance();
     }

    @Provides
    Service1 provideService1(){
        return new Service1Impl(
              this.provideRepository1(), 
              new Service2Impl(this.provideRepository2(), //this param 
              // needs service 1 which again needs service 2 and would 
              // be a loop);
    }
}
```

This is only two services forming loops within themselves while creating modules. Consider a system having multiple services in the same fashion. I am not sure how to go about this. In Spring, it's easy to implement but I cannot use it due to certain constraints. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a design issue (code smell) with having cyclic dependencies (circular dependencies)

Comment: @Nkosi in spring its possible to autowire any service that one wants. Like service1 and service2 could be autowired in each other and call methods. How can this be achieved using dagger?